# How to modify a series with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an series that is like this:

```
0 2019.0

1 2020.0

2 2018.0
```

...

And I want to end like this

```
0 STROS-ANULAC 2018_19

1 STROS-ANULAC 2019_20

2 STROS-ANULAC 2017_18
```

...

I know that I can loop trough it but I want to know if it's a better way of doing this (using pandas). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you just need to use string methods to join up the rows along the index.

the key method here will be `.astype(str)` to convert any numeric objects into strings.

```
s = pd.Series([2019,2020,2018])

s = 'STROS-ANULAC  ' + (s - 1).astype(str) + '_' + (s - 2000).astype(str)

print(s)

0    STROS-ANULAC  2018_19
1    STROS-ANULAC  2019_20
2    STROS-ANULAC  2017_18
```